# Pandas series removing duplicates issue

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series with duplicates which I am trying to get rid of

```
0     RWAY001
1     RWAY001
2     RWAY002
3     RWAY002
...
112    RWAY057
113    RWAY057
114    RWAY058
115    RWAY058
Length: 116
```

Drop.duplicates() seems to cut the length to 58 but the index  still seems to go from 0 to 116 but just skipping the duplicates:

```
0      RWAY001
2      RWAY002
...
112    RWAY057
114    RWAY058
Length: 58
```

So it seems the rows in between still exist with NaN value. I tried dropna() but it does not have any effect on the data.

This is the code I have:

```
  df = pd.read_csv(path + flnm)
  fields = df.file
  fields = fields.drop_duplicates()
  print fields
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True`:

```
fields.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Or:

```
fields = fields.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'file': {0: 'RWAY001', 1: 'RWAY001', 2: 'RWAY002', 3: 'RWAY002', 115: 'RWAY058', 113: 'RWAY057', 112: 'RWAY057', 114: 'RWAY058'}})
print (df)
        file
0    RWAY001
1    RWAY001
2    RWAY002
3    RWAY002
112  RWAY057
113  RWAY057
114  RWAY058
115  RWAY058

print (df.file.drop_duplicates())
0      RWAY001
2      RWAY002
112    RWAY057
114    RWAY058
Name: file, dtype: object

print (df.file.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
0    RWAY001
1    RWAY002
2    RWAY057
3    RWAY058
Name: file, dtype: object
```